# None API function could be found scripting a YouTube object

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to manipulate an Youtube object via JavaScript. But once I call a function like seekTo(), JS engine tells me there is no such function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
<div id="ytapiplayer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "ytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/tS3J2BkLamQ?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", 
               "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ytplayer.seekTo(10,true)">seek</a>
```

There are *three* IDs in the [official example](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Examples). I tried them all with no result.

Fiefox 6 AFAIK

**UPD** Finally I figured out such code must be run at the server side.

Comment: The reason all `ids` fail the same is because they don't matter. You get to choose any id you want with the `atts` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: the code should be run on the server side due to restrictions of Flash.

Answer (score 2):

You will first need to make sure your `ytplayer` JS object is set to the right thing - you can do this inside a call to [`onYouTubePlayerReady()`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#onYouTubePlayerReady):

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  // create a global variable called ytplayer
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer"); 
}
```

I think the API calls this function for you once the player has loaded - you don't need to register it.

Edit: here is a link to a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cZdZK/

Comment: Variable 'ytplayer' is pre-available even without getElementById; it is a HTMLObjectElement. However I've placed an alert into that callback - it's not called for me: http://pastebin.com/w191azuT

Comment: Hm. Are there any errors on the js console? Is swfobject.js installed on your server? If you don't have it, you can link directly to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js

Comment: I created a working example JS fiddle and updated the answer - let me know if you need any more help :)

Comment: There are no errors in the console. swfobject is placed in the same dir. Sorry, cannot find a free one-time HTML hosting.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, it works on JS fiddle! But not on my PC :)  Looking at the JS fiddle code I've added onload() handler but still with no result. I'll investigate it further.

Comment: Hm. When I run the example in your pastebin link I get the alert.  (See http://jsfiddle.net/cZdZK/1/ ) Maybe something else on your page is affecting it?

Comment: Finally I figured out such code must be run at the server side.